# Border keep ratio when using scale transform

Tags: wpf

I might've dreamed it, but I remember somewhere I read that it was possible to use a scale transform to change the size of a border, and that there's a property that will keep the border width to what it was before using the scale (what I might've dreamed is this property, not the scale transform =P).

So, normally, if I have a border with BorderWidth of 1, and I scale it to make it bigger, the BorderWidth will look like it is 10 or something. I want the control itself to be bigger, but the its border to keep the 1 pixel width.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just layout-transform scale a zero-width border to any size you like and wrap it in one-pixel width border.

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border Height="100" Width="100">
            <Border.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
            </Border.LayoutTransform>
            <TextBlock Text="Some text"/>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**Edit:**

OK, take two for when the scaling is coming in externally.

Here is a little markup demo with a canvas being transformed and containing a border:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:DescalingConverter x:Key="descalingConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Canvas Name="canvas">
        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <Border BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=canvas, Converter={StaticResource descalingConverter}}"
                BorderBrush="Black" Width="100" Height="100">
            <TextBlock Text="Some text"/>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

and here is the de-scaling converter:

```
public class DescalingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var element = value as FrameworkElement;
        var transform = element.LayoutTransform as ScaleTransform;
        if (transform == null) return 1.0;
        return 1.0 / transform.ScaleX;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that the converter is not robust and is only from demonstration purposes.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It would work, but the problem is that my border is inside a canvas, and it is the canvas what is being transformed, hence, putting the 1 thickness border outside of the border will render the same result. Maybe I should've been specific on that. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Added an approach for your situation.

Comment: Haha nice! I'll try it in the next hour and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful! It worked! I had to adapt it a little to my code here. Basically I'm drawing that border in the OnRender of some control I made, and in there I get the LayoutTransform of the parent (in this case the Canvas I mentioned), and from there I get the ScaleX and divide the thickness of the Pen I'm using by the scale factor. If I could, I'd vote 9 more times. Thanks!!

Comment: Just for completion of information this piece of code works great but ONLY trigger once when first loading the window unless you call refresh of the binding manually. So if you are like me and have a slider that the scale on the element is binded on then simply invoke your refresh binding on the binding update of the element name your border is binded on. this should work most of the time as binding are asynchronous it's not 100% fail safe.